# Xiaomi MI device not picking image from Gallery

Tags: android, imageview

I have a very weird issue. I am picking an image from a gallery the code is working properly on all the devices like Nokia 6 , One Plus X. When it 
comes to xiaomi devices the image is not getting set on `ImageView` .

Can anyone help me out on how to fix this issue ?
   I have to pick multiple images. 

Code to pick image from gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Comment: "but when it comes to xiaomi devices the image is not getting set on ImageView" -- your question does not show any code for doing this.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..actually it is not some special code i am using Picasso in which i am just passing image path to load images , i have also tried with Glide as well but none of these worked

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing your code for using Picasso or Glide. There is no "image path". Pass the `Uri` to the library (and, in the case of multiple images, give the image `Uri` the proper way).

Comment: @Saurabhsharma Any exception OR error log are u getting from there?? Than plz paste it along with question

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha no exception is coming

Comment: @CommonsWare The issue is on some Xiomi devices the result code is coming as "0" which is for RESULT_CANCELED. Also the data us coming as null. Facing this problem in this sample project as well: https://github.com/rifqimfahmi/BetterImageUpload

Answer (score -1):

Remove multiple images selection if you are selecting then you need to resolve it by Cursor in a new String array.

and also add these two lines in your code:

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

   android:largeHeap="true"
```