# Pick multiple images form gallery in Redmi mobile

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

Below code is not working in **Redmi 4A**...it's working maximum devices it not working only Redmi 4A..i donot know it's throwing **Nullpointer exception**

**Error:**

> Exeception: something went wrongjava.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.content.ClipData.getItemCount()' on a null object reference

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            galleryIntent.setType("video/*, image/*");  // galleryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
            galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PreviewImages.this,"WEdfsdfsdfdsfsfdsf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
            galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});
            galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        }
```

Here is **OnActivityResult**

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data
                Log.e("previewimages"," **onActivityResult   ");
                String[] filePathColumn = {     MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    if(data.getData()!=null){
                    Log.e("previewimages"," **single  image selections   ");
                    String[] files = new String[1];
                    Log.e("printuri result","****oneimg    "+data.getData());
                    String  realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(PreviewImages.this, data.getData());
                    files[0]  = realPath;

                    ImagepathModel imagepathModel = new ImagepathModel();
                    imagepathModel.setFilepath(realPath);
                    arrayList_copyfilepath.add(imagepathModel);

                    selectedimag_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    preview_playimagee.setEnabled(true);
                    preview_playimagee.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    displayFirstImages();
                    removepos =0;
                    if (myAnim !=null)
                        tv_add_sticker.startAnimation(myAnim);

                } else {
                    Log.e("previewimages"," **mutiple image selections   "+data.getClipData() +"   ==  "+data.getClipData().getItemCount());
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        String[] files = new String[ mClipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            String  realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(PreviewImages.this, item.getUri());

                            ImagepathModel imagepathModel = new ImagepathModel();
                            imagepathModel.setFilepath(realPath);
                            arrayList_copyfilepath.add(imagepathModel);

                            final File file = new File(realPath);
                            if (file.exists()) {

                                Log.e("fileexistes","*****          "+  "   File is existss      "  + realPath);
                            }else {
                                Log.e("fileexistes","*****          "+  "   Nofilefounds      ");

                            }

                           // preview_playimagee.setImageURI(data.getData());
                            Log.e("filepaths","****uris    "+item.getUri());
                            Log.e("filepaths","multipleimages          "+"    realpath \n "+realPath);


                        }


                         preview_playimagee.setEnabled(true);
                         preview_playimagee.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         selectedimag_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                         displayFirstImages();
                         removepos = 0;
                        if (myAnim !=null)
                         tv_add_sticker.startAnimation(myAnim);
                     }
                }
            } else {
                if (arrayList_copyfilepath.size() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Atleast One Pick",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.e("Exeception","something went wrong"+e.toString());
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/issues/112

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you..but  i don't want use any lib sir becase  max device it's working ..

Comment: @GowthamanM My app is also crashing when I picked an image from Redmi but it works in almost device. still, I did not get any solution, But maybe when I picked an image from Redmin, the gallery always ask "Ok" after choosing images from  Redmi but other device did not ask when you have chosen image, and another problem is when you choose an image from Motorola device, then the app will also crash their because it does not have default file manager.

Comment: @Selvin this is different problem, this is not a simple `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Selvin please read my question completely...it's working all the devices...i donot what is the cause getting null pointer exception...i know how to fix nullpointer exception

Comment: Lol, yes, it is simple NPE problem ... ClipData object is null ... the line is in the exception itself ...

Comment: @selvin no, I also have been facing the same problem for a month, I could not find right solution regarding this.

Comment: again yes, it is ... it's from his log statment ...

Comment: @farhana thank you for your valuable response..i checked motorola it's wrking fine..i facing problem in redmi 4A only sir

Comment: @Selvin we want to know why only one device creating the same problem where almost devices do not create `nullpointer`, If you have any suggestion regarding this, Please let us know.

Comment: @Selvin ok fine..do have any idea  how to fix.i selecting the image even it's throws null pointer exception..

Comment: It is all in the duplicated question ...

Comment: @Selvin we know this is `NullPointerException` and  `ClipData` is null, but why Intent is returning null in `redmi`.

Comment: @farhana is there any workaround solution..how to overcome this please tell me sir

Comment: obviosuly because redmi's gallery doesn't implement it

Comment: @Selvin can you brief it more.

Comment: Xaoim modify the source of (or make custom) gallery which doesn't support it ... you have to live with that ... and do a null check ... you may send comunicate to the user to install other galley like google's photo to make your app works on redmi devices

Comment: @Selvin  it means no Solution regarding this. Okay, For example somewhere I saw the code where the data is picked individually for the specific device. It may work.

Comment: There is a small chance that they are returning it not as `ClipData` but in some different way ... but it would involve to have redmi device and do returned Intent dump to find where Xaomi hide it ... other way is to fill some bug report to xaomi and pray for the fix

Comment: @GowthamanM did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977914/selecting-image-from-gallery-not-working-on-redmi-note-4) ?

Comment: @farhana no use.., its not working.

Comment: @GowthamanM did you use File Provider?

Comment: @farhana File Provider it's working well all the devices no issuse in that..using this https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive