# onActivityForResult data is null

Tags: android

Recently, I updated a project with android 7.0 and upper.
I figured out the provider problem.

When I take photo and use onActivityForResult to resize the image or show it. I find the data is null. I wonder why? I have tried  several ways to get Uri.

But the data is null.

```
 //A button click to call this.
        Uri tempUri;
        private void takePhoto() {
            if (isSdcardExisting()) {
                //create a file.
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesAbsolutePath(this),HERO_IMAGE);
                if(file.exists()){
                    try {
                        file.delete();
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //use a class to deal uri problem android 7.0 problem.
                Uri uri = FileProvider7.getUriForFile(this,file);
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                //put some keys to intent 
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
                /*
                 * grant uri
                 * 
                 * the temp sulution : 
                 * tempUri = uri;
                 */
                FileProvider7.grantUriPermission(this,cameraIntent,uri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "请插入SD卡", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
                return;
            }else{
                switch (requestCode){
                    case CODE_TAKE_PHOTO:
                        /**
                         * the requestCode and resultCode is right,but the data is null
                         * I wander how to use this.
                         * 
                         * the temp solution is to define a Uri obejct to store the uri.
                         * 
                         * if(tempUri != null)
                         *      resize(tempUri);
                         */
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: data ---> " + data);
                        if(data != null){
                            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: bundle ---> " + bundle);
                            if(bundle != null){
                                Uri resizeUri = bundle.getParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: resizeUri ---> " + resizeUri);
                                String imageType = bundle.getString("outputFormat");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: imageType ---> " + imageType);
                                Uri uri = data.getData();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: getData --->  " + uri);
                                resize(resizeUri);
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case CODE_SHOW_IMAGE:
                        break;
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

I found a solution that the activity needs to add action in manifest activity intent filter.But it doesn't seems to work.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.rambopan.demotryusercamera">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The log.The uri is ok,the data is null.(Android 5.0)

```
06-12 15:26:11.063 368-368/com.rambopan.demotryusercamera D/XADAX.FileProvider7: getUriForFile: ---> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rambopan.demotryusercamera/files/hero
06-12 15:26:32.624 368-368/com.rambopan.demotryusercamera D/XADAX.MainActivity: onActivityResult: data ---> null
```

Comment: please check some other devices

Comment: add your manifest

Comment: What does it matter that `data==null` ? You dont need it. You have your `file`.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that code. Dont create an empty file already. It serves nothing.

Comment: @Gowthaman M  I have two phone,(Mi2S , ReadMiS2),they neither works.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564112/android-camera-onactivityresult-intent-is-null-if-it-had-extras?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098009/pick-multiple-images-form-gallery-in-redmi-mobile............Basically MI mbl having some issuse..so check it some other devices

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image from the `uri` variable that you are sending in `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);`

Comment: emmmm……I used this,the question is the data is null.